# How to login to google accounts using awesomium in C#.net

Tags: c#, awesomium

I'm trying to login to https://accounts.google.com with awesomium, but got error on setting password field after click next button.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Awesomium.Core;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(new WebPreferences { WebSecurity = false });
            using (WebView webViewBrowser = WebCore.CreateWebView(1024, 768, session, WebViewType.Offscreen))
            {
                webViewBrowser.ConsoleMessage += webViewBrowser_ConsoleMessage;
                webViewBrowser.LoadingFrameComplete += webViewBrowser_LoadingFrameComplete;

                webViewBrowser.Source = new Uri("http://www.blogger.com/");

                if (WebCore.UpdateState == WebCoreUpdateState.NotUpdating) WebCore.Run();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        static void webViewBrowser_ConsoleMessage(object sender, ConsoleMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print("{0} at {1}: {2} at '{3}'", e.EventName, e.LineNumber, e.Message, e.Source);
        }

        static void webViewBrowser_LoadingFrameComplete(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.IsMainFrame) return;

            WebView webViewBrowser = sender as WebView;

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Page Title: {0}", webViewBrowser.Title));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Loaded URL: {0}", webViewBrowser.Source));
            dynamic Email = (JSObject)webViewBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementById('Email');");
            Email["value"] = "test@gmail.com";

            dynamic btn = (JSObject)webViewBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementById('next');");
            btn.click();

            dynamic Passwd = (JSObject)webViewBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementById('Passwd');");
            Passwd["value"] = "pass007";

            btn = (JSObject)webViewBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementById('signIn');");
            btn.click();

            BitmapSurface surface = (BitmapSurface)webViewBrowser.Surface;
            surface.SaveToPNG("result.png", true);

            WebCore.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception on line Passwd["value"] = "pass007";:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Awesomium.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: You cannot perform this operation on an
>   invalid (undefined) object.

Answer (score 1):

After entering the email and clicking 'Next'button, the page makes an AJAX call to check for email validity and only if it does exist, the input password element is created in the DOM. That will take some time.

In your code, you retrieve input password element immediately after clicking 'Next', which hasn't existed yet, hence the exception:

> You cannot perform this operation on an invalid (**undefined**) object.

The solution is to wait for the element to exist before setting the value, e.g. using a loop or if you are lazy, Thread.Sleep may suffice although it is not a recommended practice.